# MySQL 3.2 - Retrieve the last record in each group that is not null

Tags: mysql

The query below gets the last record of each group based on the largest StopTime value. Now, I want to get the last non-null record of each group but I am not sure what to change.

Sidenote: I know I am using an old version of MySql. The place where I work never upgraded.

**Query**

```
SELECT a.Date1, a.StopTime, a.RunId, a.SN, a.Test1P2
FROM table a
Left JOIN table b
    ON(a.RunId=b.RunId AND a.SN=b.SN AND a.StopTime < b.StopTime)
    WHERE b.StopTime IS NULL
    GROUP BY RunId, SN
ORDER BY Date1
```

---

**Example Table**

```
Date1       StopTime    RunId    SN   Test1P2
---------------------------------------------
3/19/2019     123        Test   code1   24.5
3/19/2019     124        Test   code1   NULL
3/19/2019     125        Test   code1   32.1
3/19/2019     126        Test   code1   NULL
4/11/2019     242        Meet   code2   56.6
4/11/2019     243        Meet   code2   NULL
5/4/2019      509        Bite   code23  8.2
5/4/2019      510        Bite   code23  10.22

// added case
7/8/2019      456        NonT   code54  NULL
7/8/2019      457        NonT   code54  NULL
7/8/2019      458        NonT   code54  NULL
```

**Current Result**

```
Date1       StopTime    RunId    SN   Test1P2
---------------------------------------------           
3/19/2019     126        Test   code1   NULL
4/11/2019     243        Meet   code2   NULL
5/4/2019      510        Bite   code23  10.22
7/8/2019      458        NonT   code54  NULL
```

**Desired Result**

```
Date1       StopTime    RunId    SN   Test1P2
---------------------------------------------
3/19/2019     125        Test   code1   32.1
4/11/2019     242        Meet   code2   56.6
5/4/2019      510        Bite   code23  10.22
7/8/2019      458        NonT   code54  NULL
```

---

**Update**
I added an edge case.

**Latest code**

```
SELECT a.DATE1, a.StopTime, a.RunId, a.SN, a.Test1P2, a.Test1P2PF 
FROM table a
Left JOIN table b
    ON(a.RunId=b.RunId AND a.SN=b.SN AND a.StopTime < b.StopTime)
    WHERE b.StopTime IS NULL AND a.Test1P2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY RunId , SN
ORDER BY DATE1
```

Comment: Add `WHERE TestIP2 IS NOT NULL` to your query.

Comment: Are you sure it's MySQL 3.2. That version reached end of life around 2005...(?)

Comment: @KenWhite I added an edge case that I forgot to include before. I want Test1P2 to be null if there are no values in the group.

Comment: @TheImpaler I believe you are right. Yes, this is MySQL 3.23 (to be exact).

Comment: 3.2 though. That's got to be some kind of record

Comment: Your original query returns an indeterminate result. In consequence, your 'latest' query is a step in the wrong direction. Just sayin'

Comment: And surely it's meaningless to order by a malformed date !?!

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry The date is the primary key.

Comment: New information: subqueries and union were introduced after 3.2 so I can't use either of those.

Comment: Well, that's obviously not true, because date repeats. So let's try again: how do you uniquely identify rows on this table?

Comment: @Strawberry woops, it's actually Date1 and StopTime

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with MySQL 3.2 for ages now, so I'm not sure this query was valid then. You can try:

```
select *
from table
where (RunId, SN, StopTime) in (
  select RunId, SN, max(StopTime)
  from table
  where Test1P2 is not null
  group by RunId, SN
)
```

Comment: This does not work but Ken White's response brought me closer to what I want. There is one more edge case that I forgot to mention earlier but I have added it now.

Comment: Turns out subqueries was introduced in version 4.0 so I don't think it's possible to do the querying that I want in 3.2

Comment: @cheekydeeky Was worth a try. I don't really have any way of testing the query. Unfortunately all web sites such as db-fiddle.com, sqlfiddle.com, or dbfiddle.uk have MySQL version 5.0 as the oldest available one.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I might have to perform this query in the local side (C# code) rather than the server side.

Comment: As a side note, I would encourage your place to upgrade. Not only for them, but for your benefit too. MySQL has made great progress, and your career can benefit ($) from the new features available in version 8.x. Just a note.

Comment: Apparently they have thought about it but never went forward with it because of how they structured the tables or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Impaler's answer, You just need to add an UNION ALL clause to handle Null values group -

```
select *
from table
where (RunId, SN, StopTime) in (select RunId, SN, max(StopTime)
                                  from table
                                 where Test1P2 is not null
                                 group by RunId, SN)
union all
select Date1, MAX(StopTime), RunId, SN, NULL
from table
where Test1P2 is null
group by Date1, RunId, SN
```

Comment: mySQL 3.2 doesn't support subqueries nor union. I am starting to believe I can't perform this action in this version of mySQL.